# Type safety warning in collection

Tags: java, generics, collections

I've below code snippet where am trying to get Max date group wise. Code is runing fine, but it showing warning stating that Type safety: Uncheck Invocation. What is being missed to be checked ?

```
class Movie<T> implements Comparator<T> {

    static LinkedHashMap<String, List<Date>> listOfDates = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<Date>>();

    static {

        listOfDates.put("1", new ArrayList<Date>());
        listOfDates.put("2", new ArrayList<Date>());
        listOfDates.put("3", new ArrayList<Date>());
        listOfDates.put("4", new ArrayList<Date>());
        listOfDates.put("5", new ArrayList<Date>());
        listOfDates.put("6", new ArrayList<Date>());
        listOfDates.put("7", new ArrayList<Date>());
        listOfDates.put("8", new ArrayList<Date>());
        listOfDates.put("9", new ArrayList<Date>());
        listOfDates.put("10", new ArrayList<Date>());
        listOfDates.put("11", new ArrayList<Date>());
        listOfDates.put("12", new ArrayList<Date>());

    }

    public static void loadDates(String inpDate) {

        String[] dates = "27-05-201901-01-2019,02-01-2019,03-01-2019,04-01-2019,01-02-2019,01-03-2019,21-03-2019,20-05-2019,21-05-2019,22-05-2019,26-05-2019".split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {

            try {
                Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(dates[i]);
                String mth = Integer
                        .toString(date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate().getMonthValue());
                listOfDates.get(mth).add(date);

            } catch (ParseException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        System.out.println(finalString(listOfDates));
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Object date1, Object date2) {
        Date d1 = (Date) date1;
        Date d2 = (Date) date2;
        int i = 0;
        if (d1.compareTo(d2) == 0) {
            i = 0;
        }

        else if (d1.compareTo(d2) > 0) {

            i = 1;
        }

        else if (d1.compareTo(d2) < 0) {

            i = -1;
        }
        return i;
    }

    public static String finalString(LinkedHashMap<String, List<Date>> dates) {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder finalsb = new StringBuilder();

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Date>> entry : dates.entrySet()) {

            if (entry.getValue().isEmpty() || entry.getValue().size() == 0) {

                sb.append("        ").append(",");

            } else if (entry.getValue().size() == 1) {

                sb.append(dateFormat.format(entry.getValue().get(0))).append(",");

            }

            else {

                sb.append(dateFormat.format(Collections.max(entry.getValue(), new Movie()))).append(",");    //WARNING
            }

        }

        int lastIndexOfTab = sb.lastIndexOf(",");
        finalsb.append(sb.substring(0, lastIndexOfTab));
        return finalsb.toString();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        loadDates("Enter");

    }

}
```

But am geting warning in line where `//WARNING` is comment in else condtiton.

May I know please why am getting this below warning ?

```
Type safety: Unchecked invocation max(List<Date>, Movie) of the generic method max(Collection<? extends T>, Comparator<? super T>) of type Collections
```

Why its coming and how should I avoid it ..?

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Because you declared Movie as a generic type, and yet you're not providing the generic type of the new Movie you're creating. Also, movies don't compare anything so please don't call a Comparator class Movie. And when a Comparator is only able to compare Dates, please make it implement Comparator<Date> and not make it generic.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `Comparable<T>` rather than `Comparator<T>`

Comment: @kumesana, "movies don't compare anything so please don't call a Comparator class Movie" I didnt get this ..!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a movie is a piece of video that you watch on your TV, or at the theater. It's typically not something that performs any sort of comparison. Therefore, you should never think of using a movie to compare stuff.

Comment: @kumesana, but I'n my code am using Comparator class Movie in Collections to get max date..! So what you'll suggest..? How my code should be ?

Comment: Well for starters you don't need to involve any kind of new comparator, because you're comparing Dates and they already know how to compare to each other. You'd just use Collections.max() without specifying any comparator. But even when you do need to make new comparators, then whatever you call them, don't call them Movie. Because a movie is not something that compares stuff. Call it ThatThingComparator.

Comment: To complement what kumesana said, a typical name for a comparator would express the criteria, e.g. [`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) or [`Comparator.naturalOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--), the latter being what you need. Other typical names would be `class FileByName` or `FileByLastModified`, though nowadays, nobody needs to write such classes, as `Comparator.comparing(File::name)` or `Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified)` would do.

Comment: As a side note, what’s the point of this `finalsb`? Why don’t you just `return sb.substring(0, lastIndexOfTab);`?

Comment: @Holger, To remove last tab from the string ...! :)

Comment: That’s what `sb.substring(0, lastIndexOfTab)` does. But why are you copying this string into another `StringBuilder` (`finalsb`) and creating another identical string via `.toString()`, instead of just returning the substring as suggested by my previous comment? `return sb.substring(0, lastIndexOfTab);` does already the intended job. You could also use `sb.setLength(lastIndexOfTab); return sb.toString();`. In either case, there is no need for a second `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Holger, You are right ..!

Comment: @Holger, Can you please share any example how to use your logic you had menioned in your last comment ..? "To complement what kumesana said, a typical name *"

Comment: The example usage would be `Collections.max(entry.getValue(), Comparator.naturalOrder())`. But the natural order is so fundamental that you don’t even need that. You can just use `Collections.max(entry.getValue())` without specifying a `Comparator`.